# how print out the output in a new file perl

Tags: perl

How can I print in a directory the output of the variable $newFile ? How can I use 'cp' to do that ?
After modifications, my code looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Copy 'cp';

# binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8") ;
# warn Dumper \@repertoire;

my @rep= glob('/home/test/Bureau/Perl/Test/*'); # output to copy in this dir
foreach my $file (@rep)
{
    open(IN, $file) or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";
    while (<IN>)
    {
    my ($firstCol, $secondCol) = split(/","/, $_); 

    $firstCol =~ s/http:\/\//_/g;
    $secondCol =~ s/\(.+\)/ /ig;
    my $LCsecondCol = lc($secondCol);
    chomp($secondCol);
    chomp($LCsecondCol);
    my $newFile = "$firstCol:($secondCol|$LCsecondCol);";
    $newFile =~ s/=//g;
    print "$newFile\n";

    }
    close(IN);
}
```

Comment: `cp` is a unix command that makes copies of files that are already on the filesystem; of course it doesn't know what's in variables in a perl program that runs it.

Comment: @Wooble: but the double quotes will *interpolate* the values of the variables into the string that forms the command. The shell will never see the variables' names, only their contents

Comment: You are using File::Copy… why are you calling `system` to get to `cp`?

Comment: The question talks about printing output to a file, and then has code that attempts to copy files. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, but there are a number of strange things in your script. Try stepping through your script in the debugger cheking the value of all your variables and. this might enable you to tell us where you scripts behaviour differs from the expected making it possible for us to help you.

Comment: You call `glob` once, in scalar context and iterates over this single value. Basically your outer `foreach` loop is equivalent to `my $filename = $repertoire`. Also you code shouldn't even compile with `use strict`. It should give you an 'Global symbol "$file" requires explicit package name at line 21" error

Answer (score 4):

Your program is a long way off even compiling. You should pay attention to these details

- With `use strict` in place, as it should be, you must declare all of your variables at their point of first use. The variables `@files`, `$file`, and `$newFile` are undeclared so your program won't compile
- `glob` in scalar context returns the *next* file name that matches the pattern, and is meant for use in a `while` loop. To get all of the files that match the pattern you should assign to an array, and from the commented-out `warn` statement it looks like your code used to be that way
- You should use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`. Well done for checking the status of the `open` and putting `$!` in your `die` string
- Your `$file =~ ...` line looks like it should be a substitution, and the parenthesis at the end should be a semicolon
- You have used `File::Copy` but then use `system` to copy your files. You should avoid shelling out wherever convenient, and since `File::Copy` provides a `cp` function you should use it

Something closer to a working version of your code would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy 'cp';

while (my $fileName = glob '/home/test/Bureau/Infobox/*.csv') {

    my @files = do {
        open my $in, '<', $fileName or die "Can't read file '$fileName' [$!]\n";
        print "$fileName\n" ;
        <$in>;
    };

    foreach my $file (@files) {
        my $newFile = $file =~ s/(\x{0625}\x{0646}\b.+?)\./[[    ]]/gr;
        cp $file, $newFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: I reedited my code (see my post). How can I use 'cp' to copy the output in a directory ? 'cp $file, $newFile;' wont' work. I need to print out '$newFile' in '/home/test/Bureau/Perl/Test/'. Thanks !

Comment: Your question is now a very different one. You should really raise a new question to ask something different. I still don't understand what you want to do, as you say you are both reading and writing files from `/home/test/Bureau/Perl/Test/`

Comment: The `s///` option `/r` is relatively new. If you need to do something similar on an older version of Perl replace `my $new = $old =~ s///r` with `(my $new = $old) =~ s///`